# how to build Golang for windows xp in Ubuntu?

Tags: go, ubuntu, windows-xp, mingw-w64

how to build Golang for windows xp in Ubuntu?

Golang Version: Go 1.13
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Mingw-w64 Version: 9.3 / 7.0.0-2

[image]

command:
`GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o test.exe`

[image]

In Windows XP Error:
**"Not a valid win32 application"**

thank you

Comment: The minimum requirements are Windows 7.

Comment: The referenced github is https://github.com/forensicanalysis/artifactcollector.
These github releases support Windows xp, which is listed as 1.16 in the go.mod file (the previous commit was 1.13).


I know that Windows XP supports up to version 1.10 in golang, but I was wondering if there was a way to compile using a higher version like that github, so I asked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Go uses build-in OS functions. Check you code to confirm that all class and methods are available in Windows XP, if not, you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use go version 1.10.8 to build Golang on Windows XP.

golang 1.10.8

```bash
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf go1.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

I thought there might be another way, but there is none other than this.